# TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: python, keras

I use Keras to build my model, there are two inputs in my model, whose datatype is 'int32'. And then I use keras Lamba layer to look up in the embedding matric with K.gather(reference, indices). I see that indices should be tensor of int, and I think my code meets that, I do not know why about the error. I really need help!

```
    input_A = Input(batch_shape=(128,1),name='A_input',dtype='int32')
    input_B = Input(batch_shape=(128,1),name='B_input',dtype='int32')

    input_A_ = Lambda(lambda x:K.reshape(x,(-1,)))(input_A)
    input_B_ = Lambda(lambda x:K.reshape(x, (-1,)))(input_B)

    input_A__ = Lambda(lambda x:K.cast(x,dtype='int32'))(input_A_)
    input_B__ = Lambda(lambda x:K.cast(x,dtype='int32'))(input_B_)

    embedded_text_A = Lambda(lambda x:K.gather(M1,x))(input_A__)
    embedded_text_B = Lambda(lambda x:K.gather(M1,x))(input_B__)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some enigmatic reason it will work properly if one places `K.cast()` inside the `lambda`:

```
input_A = Input(batch_shape=(128,1), name='A_input', dtype='int32')
input_B = Input(batch_shape=(128,1), name='B_input', dtype='int32')

input_A_ = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1,)))(input_A)
input_B_ = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1,)))(input_B)

embedded_text_A = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(M1, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(input_A_)
embedded_text_B = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(M1, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(input_B_)
```

Hence, `Lambda` layer makes some strange dtype conversion within.

I suppose it is some kind of bug, and my hypothesis is that implicit conversion takes place inside the `Lambda`'s `__call__` [(which is inherited from `Layer.__call__`)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L376). I can't track it, but I guess 'implicit conversion' bug is somewhere in `Layer.__call__`, but before the line [451](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L451), where the `Lambda.call` is actually invoked.